# green threads in gunicorn flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, gunicorn, gevent

I'm using gunicorn - flask setup for web service. 
Using gunicorn, I was able to make concurrent request. I'm using green threads for db operations.

```
pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
val = pool.spawn(execute_query_task, query).wait()
```

Running gunicorn with just workers and no threads working fine. 
But when I run gunicorn with threads, I was not able to receive the data in my endpoint. It just loading. When I stop the gunicorn, I was able to fetch the result. Is pool.spawn().wait() blocking the endpoint?

I monkey patch the following packages for async db opeation,

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

import psycogreen.eventlet
psycogreen.eventlet.patch_psycopg()
```